# Edit multiple Excel files at onces with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have some Excel files which have the same format: one column with product id, one with product description. Is it possible to edit all the files at once using pandas and Jupyter notebook? I want to add another column where I should have the product id concatenated with ",". So I want all my files to look like this:

Product_Id Product descripiton New column

12345             Chocolate         12345,

54321        Milk              54321,

[image]
I want to keep all the original files, don't want to combine them all into one Excel file.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you realy need to use Pandas or you can use other lib?

Comment: why would you need to edit them at once? This also works with one file after the other. Or do you mean you only want to start one script that does this?

Comment: I would like to edit them all at once because the number of files is big and I thought it's easier than to edit one file at a time.

Comment: @user2399087 I just started using Jupyter notebook & Pandas and I thought I can edit them with it. It's not really needed to use it, but I don't know another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution. Update the path to your folder where the excel files are or put the python file in the same folder and let path_to_xls as it is. Backup your original files, this one will overwrite the xls file.

```
from openpyexcel import load_workbook
import os

path_to_xls = os.getcwd() # or r'<path>'
for xls in os.listdir(path_to_xls):
    if xls.endswith(".xls") or xls.endswith(".xlsx"):
        f = load_workbook(filename=xls)
        sheet = f.active
        # Change here the name of the new column
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "New col"
        for i in range(sheet.max_row-1):
            sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=3).value = str(sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=1).value) + ","
        f.save(xls)
        f.close()
```